# mongoDB search query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For an assignment, we are given the following code:

```
db.bib.insertMany( [
      {type : "book",
         "@year": "1994",
         "title": "TCP/IP Illustrated",
         "author": {
            "last": "Stevens",
            "first": "W."
         },
         "publisher": "Addison-Wesley",
         "price": "65"
      },
      {type : "book",
         "@year": "1992",
         "title": "Unix Programming",
         "author": {
            "last": "Stevens",
            "first": "W."
         },
         "publisher": "Addison-Wesley",
         "price": "65"
      },
      {type : "book",
         "@year": "2000",
         "title": "Data on the Web",
         "author": [
            {
               "last": "Abiteboul",
               "first": "Serge"
            },
            {
               "last": "Buneman",
               "first": "Peter"
            },
            {
               "last": "Suciu",
               "first": "Dan"
            }
         ],
         "publisher": "Morgan Kaufmann",
         "price": "39"
      },
      {type : "book",
         "@year": "1999",
         "title": "Digital TV",
         "editor": {
            "last": "Gerbarg",
            "first": "Darcy",
            "affiliation": "CITI"
         },
         "publisher": "Kluwer",
         "price": "130"
      }
    ,
      {type : "journal",
      "title": "Irreproducible results",
      "editor": {
         "last": "Self",
         "first": "W."
      },
      "publisher": "SV"
   }
])
```

Using mongoDB, we are then asked to complete different search queries in order to find the desired information.  The one that I am currently stuck on is

List the titles of books published after 1995 and costing less than 100.

From my understanding, the proper query should be something along the lines of

```
db.bib.find({price: {$lt: 100}, year: {$gt: 1995}}, {title: 1, _id: 0})
```

However, this provides a blank result when it should not.  Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: *"For an assignment, we are given the following code..."* - So I guess your instructor actually intended for you to solve this yourself instead of crowdsourcing on Stack Overflow. Take at look at your fields again. They look like "strings" to me.

Comment: @NeilLunn I did attempt to solve this on my own hence why I provided an example of the direction I was headed in. Regardless of putting quotations around the numbers it still does not work

Comment: `100 != "100"` Also `"65" < "100" == false`. Work those out.

Comment: Ah.. well.. I see what you are saying. However, I cannot change that the numbers in the fields are put as strings.

Comment: Cannot? Or maybe that was the detail you were supposed to work out! People "teaching" you things are sometimes known to challenge you with such situations.

Comment: I’d strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I was not looking for someone to solve the problem, I was merely looking for guidance as if the professor will not aid me then how am I to learn otherwise? Secondly, I was correct in the assumption that this problem was absurd as he later sent out a corrected version replacing the string number values with true integers.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg also upon further reading of the "Open letter to students with Homework Problems", it clearly states "Describe the problem you are having, what your understanding of the problem is and where you are confused. For a question from a student, the best questions are often the ones that are asking how to take a single step in understanding rather than trying to leap all the way to the solution." Which I did.  Perhaps you should read the open letter yourself.

Comment: You still fail to see the main point. That the homework is there to teach you something. And this something was even already pointed out to you. After which you escalated the meta discussion on your question, instead of reading closely.

Answer (score 0):

Data type for both of the field is string. you can not compare them as numeric. Try following and it will work. using collation, you can ask MongoDB to treat them as int. you can read more about collation [here at mongodb.com](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/?jmp=university&_ga=2.48928037.2057071076.1523415011-1319295006.1518117506&_gac=1.48555026.1519965248.EAIaIQobChMInPiV3-fM2QIVRTqBCh2oxQfvEAAYASAAEgKyQPD_BwE).

```
db.bib.find({$and: [{"@year": {$gt: "1995"}}, {price: {$lt: "100"}}]}).collation({
  locale: "en_US",
  numericOrdering: true
});
```